# How to change width of a Sidenav in Angular Material Design?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

No matter what screen size I use, the Sidenav is always the same size. I tried adding attributes such as 
- flex
- flex="85" (to get 85% of its container)

Can't seem to find a good approach.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In angular material, md-sidenav has these attributes:

```
width: 304px;
min-width: 304px;
```

That's why the width will be fixed at 304 px no matter what device you use.
So if you want to change your sidenav width you'll have to change the css a bit.

If you're fine with supporting only modern browsers, you can change it to a vw measure (1/100th of the viewport width) and add it to a separate css file. The code will look something like this:

```
md-sidenav, 
md-sidenav.md-locked-open, 
md-sidenav.md-closed.md-locked-open-add-active {
    min-width: 200px !important;
    width: 85vw !important;
    max-width: 400px !important;
}
```

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/cXfJzxsAFXA3Lh4TiWUk?p=preview

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me and I'm struggling to understand why!

Comment: This seems to kill the animation of it opening though.

Answer (score 8):

The answer submitted by user3587412 allowed me to change the width but I was having the same problem as Craig Shearer with it killing the animation. So I tried a few different things and came up with this.

```
 md-sidenav.md-locked-open {
   width: 250px;
   min-width: 250px;
   max-width: 250px;
 }
```

I'm not sure if that is the proper way but it seemed to work for me.

Comment: Working but when the animation open the sidebar animation go to `304px` and then take the override width. Not sure how to handle this better.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to user3587412 I could find easily the required styles.
To get the md-sidenav to adjust to a flex parent just override

```
md-sidenav, 
md-sidenav.md-locked-open, 
md-sidenav.md-closed.md-locked-open-add-active {
    min-width: 0px !important;
    width: auto !important;
    max-width: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

After trying different CSS in this thread I end up with :

```
md-sidenav,
md-sidenav.md-locked-open-add-active,
md-sidenav.md-closed.md-locked-open-add-active,
md-sidenav.md-locked-open {
  width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

I'm currently on angular-material `1.0.8` and tested with Chrome `50` only.

With this CSS what works for me :

- Animation close and open OK
- When locked OK
- When not locked OK

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone comes here using the latest `mat-sidenav`, you can explicitly set the width on the the element.

```css
mat-sidenav {
  width: 200px;
}
```

The docs caution against using percentage based sizes.
https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview#setting-the-sidenavs-size

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat "jank" solution, but it doesn't mess with the animations at all. The sidenav automatically resizes itself in order of the items inside it to fit perfectly. As such, you can just add a span with the width of your choice to the mat-drawer to set a minimum size. Note that this only works to set a minimum width, and not a maximum width.
`<span style="height: 0px; width: 200px; display: inline-block;"></span>`

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue, as well -- even though the `304px` width is plenty, I had a card in the content area to the right that was squeezing the sidenav.  So, using the flex grid I was able to add `<md-sidenav flex="15" class="md-sidenav-left ...` to get the width I wanted without overriding CSS.  It sounds like this didn't work for you, so maybe it has to do with the layout options in your design...

Comment: What if the sidenav is being generated by a service instead of being written directly in as an ``md-sidenav`` directive?  I'm caught in a delimma of whether I should remove the service in order to just use a directive, but it pains me to do so.

Comment: my bad, I just realized that the sidenav tag was just in the index page and being manipulated by the Service, not generated by the service.